# How to use from_json with schema as string (i.e. a JSON-encoded schema)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading a stream from Kafka, and I convert the value from Kafka ( which is JSON ) in to Structure.

`from_json` has a variant that takes a schema of type `String`, but I could not find a sample. Please advise what is wrong in the below code.

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input '(' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT',

== SQL ==
STRUCT ( `firstName`: STRING, `lastName`: STRING, `email`: STRING, `addresses`: ARRAY ( STRUCT ( `city`: STRING, `state`: STRING, `zip`: STRING )  )  ) 
-------^^^

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:217)
```

**Program**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws AnalysisException {
    String master = "local[*]";
    String brokers = "quickstart:9092";
    String topics = "simple_topic_6";

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder().appName(EmployeeSchemaLoader.class.getName())
            .master(master).getOrCreate();

   String employeeSchema = "STRUCT ( firstName: STRING, lastName: STRING, email: STRING, " +
            "addresses: ARRAY ( STRUCT ( city: STRING, state: STRING, zip: STRING )  )  ) ";

    SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
    context.setLogLevel("ERROR");
    SQLContext sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext();

    Dataset<Row> employeeDataset = sparkSession.readStream().
            format("kafka").
            option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
            .option("subscribe", topics).load();
    employeeDataset.printSchema();
    employeeDataset = employeeDataset.withColumn("strValue", employeeDataset.col("value").cast("string"));
    employeeDataset = employeeDataset.withColumn("employeeRecord",
            functions.from_json(employeeDataset.col("strValue"),employeeSchema, new HashMap<>()));

    employeeDataset.printSchema();
    employeeDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("employeeView");

    sparkSession.catalog().listTables().show();

    sqlCtx.sql("select * from employeeView").show();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question helped me to find that the variant of `from_json` with `String`-based schema was only available in Java and has [recently](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20775) been added to Spark API for Scala in the upcoming 2.3.0. I've so long lived with the strong belief that Spark API for Scala was always the most feature-rich and your question helped me to learn it should not have been so before the change in 2.3.0 (!)

Back to your question, you can define the string-based schema in JSON or DDL format actually.

Writing JSON by hand may be a bit cumbersome and so I'd take a different approach (that given I'm a Scala developer is fairly easy).

Let's first define the schema using Spark API for Scala.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val addressesSchema = new StructType()
  .add($"city".string)
  .add($"state".string)
  .add($"zip".string)
val schema = new StructType()
  .add($"firstName".string)
  .add($"lastName".string)
  .add($"email".string)
  .add($"addresses".array(addressesSchema))
scala> schema.printTreeString
root
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |-- addresses: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- zip: string (nullable = true)
```

That seems to match your schema, doesn't it?

With that convert the schema to a JSON-encoded string was a breeze with `json` method.

```scala
val schemaAsJson = schema.json
```

`schemaAsJson` is exactly your JSON string which looks pretty...hmmm...complex. For the display purposes I'd rather use `prettyJson` method.

```
scala> println(schema.prettyJson)
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "firstName",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "lastName",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "email",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "addresses",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "elementType" : {
        "type" : "struct",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "city",
          "type" : "string",
          "nullable" : true,
          "metadata" : { }
        }, {
          "name" : "state",
          "type" : "string",
          "nullable" : true,
          "metadata" : { }
        }, {
          "name" : "zip",
          "type" : "string",
          "nullable" : true,
          "metadata" : { }
        } ]
      },
      "containsNull" : true
    },
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  } ]
}
```

That's your schema in JSON.

You can use `DataType` and "validate" the JSON string (using [DataType.fromJson](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.scala#L113) that Spark uses under the covers for `from_json`).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
val dt = DataType.fromJson(schemaAsJson)
scala> println(dt.sql)
STRUCT<`firstName`: STRING, `lastName`: STRING, `email`: STRING, `addresses`: ARRAY<STRUCT<`city`: STRING, `state`: STRING, `zip`: STRING>>>
```

All seems fine. Mind if I'm checking this out with a sample dataset?

```scala
val rawJsons = Seq("""
  {
    "firstName" : "Jacek",
    "lastName" : "Laskowski",
    "email" : "jacek@japila.pl",
    "addresses" : [
      {
        "city" : "Warsaw",
        "state" : "N/A",
        "zip" : "02-791"
      }
    ]
  }
""").toDF("rawjson")
val people = rawJsons
  .select(from_json($"rawjson", schemaAsJson, Map.empty[String, String]) as "json")
  .select("json.*") // <-- flatten the struct field
  .withColumn("address", explode($"addresses")) // <-- explode the array field
  .drop("addresses")  // <-- no longer needed
  .select("firstName", "lastName", "email", "address.*") // <-- flatten the struct field
scala> people.show
+---------+---------+---------------+------+-----+------+
|firstName| lastName|          email|  city|state|   zip|
+---------+---------+---------------+------+-----+------+
|    Jacek|Laskowski|jacek@japila.pl|Warsaw|  N/A|02-791|
+---------+---------+---------------+------+-----+------+
```