# Scala Spark - Split JSON column to multiple columns

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Scala noob, using **Spark 2.3.0**.
I'm creating a DataFrame using a udf that creates a JSON String column:

```
val result: DataFrame = df.withColumn("decrypted_json", instance.decryptJsonUdf(df("encrypted_data")))
```

it outputs as follows:

```
+----------------+---------------------------------------+
| encrypted_data | decrypted_json                        |
+----------------+---------------------------------------+
|eyJleHAiOjE1 ...| {"a":547.65 , "b":"Some Data"}        |
+----------------+---------------------------------------+
```

The UDF is an external code, that I can't change. I would like to split the decrypted_json column into individual columns so the output DataFrame will be like so:

```
+----------------+----------------------+
| encrypted_data | a      | b           |
+----------------+--------+-------------+
|eyJleHAiOjE1 ...| 547.65 | "Some Data" |
+----------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried from_jason as described at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#from_json-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query JSON data column using Spark DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069282/how-to-query-json-data-column-using-spark-dataframes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Below solution is inspired by one of the solutions given by @Jacek Laskowski:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val JsonSchema = new StructType()
  .add($"a".string)
  .add($"b".string)
val schema = new StructType()
  .add($"encrypted_data".string)
  .add($"decrypted_json".array(JsonSchema))

val schemaAsJson = schema.json

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
val dt = DataType.fromJson(schemaAsJson)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val rawJsons = Seq("""
  {
    "encrypted_data" : "eyJleHAiOjE1",
    "decrypted_json" : [
      {
        "a" : "547.65",
        "b" : "Some Data"
      }
    ]
  }
""").toDF("rawjson")

val people = rawJsons
  .select(from_json($"rawjson", schemaAsJson, Map.empty[String, String]) as "json")
  .select("json.*") // <-- flatten the struct field
  .withColumn("address", explode($"decrypted_json")) // <-- explode the array field
  .drop("decrypted_json")  // <-- no longer needed
  .select("encrypted_data", "address.*") // <-- flatten the struct field
```

[image: output]

Please go through **[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967562/how-to-use-from-json-with-schema-as-string-i-e-a-json-encoded-schema)** for the original solution with the explanation.
I hope that helps.

Comment: How to make the header be something like "encrypted_data, json_a, json_b", i.e., adding "json_" prefix to the fields of json?

Answer (score 0):

Using `from_jason` you can give parse the JSON into a Struct type then select columns from that dataframe. You will need to know the schema of the json. Here is how -

```
    val sparkSession = //create spark session
    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val jsonData = """{"a":547.65 , "b":"Some Data"}"""
    val schema = {StructType(
      List(
        StructField("a", DoubleType, nullable = false),
        StructField("b", StringType, nullable = false)
      ))}

    val df = sparkSession.createDataset(Seq(("dummy data",jsonData))).toDF("string_column","json_column")
    val dfWithParsedJson = df.withColumn("json_data",from_json($"json_column",schema))

    dfWithParsedJson.select($"string_column",$"json_column",$"json_data.a", $"json_data.b").show()
```

Result

```
+-------------+------------------------------+------+---------+
|string_column|json_column                   |a     |b        |
+-------------+------------------------------+------+---------+
|dummy data   |{"a":547.65 , "b":"Some Data"}|547.65|Some Data|
+-------------+------------------------------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what exactly should I pass as the schema?

Comment: Schema of the json needs to be passed. I think my code has an extra quot. I will fix when I get time.